# How do you properly set a thumbnail for an embed in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm having trouble with this line of code for a discord.py bot:

```
content.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
```

When I run this bot on my local computer, the embed appears properly, but I get the following error when I push the same code to Heroku:

```
2021-05-02T16:02:41.514038+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-05-02T16:02:41.514096+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 965, in invoke
2021-05-02T16:02:41.514096+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
2021-05-02T16:02:41.514179+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 798, in invoke
2021-05-02T16:02:41.514180+00:00 app[worker.1]:     await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
2021-05-02T16:02:41.514205+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 123, in wrapped
2021-05-02T16:02:41.514206+00:00 app[worker.1]:     raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
2021-05-02T16:02:41.514257+00:00 app[worker.1]: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'avatar_url'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url`?

Comment: Yeah, same problem occurs

Comment: Are you using an outdated version of `discord.py` or a selfbot?

Comment: I've used the install command in both my local computer and the Heroku console so I would assume discord.py is fully up to date.

Comment: Have you added the Python buildpack?

Comment: Yes, if you mean the requirements.txt, procfile and things like that. It is mainly the embed that is causing me trouble, as other commands that don't use embed thumbnails are working fine.

Comment: I think I may have found the issue - I run 3.7 on my computer but heroku runs 3.9. Now the question is how do I downgrade the python version on Heroku?

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is that this function can only be injected:
Correct answer:

```
embed.set_thumbnail (url = channel.member.avatar_url)
```

You will find a bunch of embedded videos like this.